# how to create list of dictionary in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have some names and scores as follows

```
input = {
        'Maths': dict(Mohsen=19, Sadegh=18, Hafez=15),
        'Physics': dict(Sadegh=16, Hafez=17, Mohsen=17),
        'Chemistry': dict(Hafez=13),
        'Literature': dict(Sadegh=14),
        'Biology': dict(Mohsen=16, Sadegh=10),
    }
```

if a person don't have any lesson its score consider zero also get avrege of scores's person and sort final list by averge and i want to  get an output like this.

```
answer = [
        dict(Name='Sadegh', Literature=14, Chemistry=0, Maths=18, Physics=16, Biology=10, Average=11.6),
        dict(Name='Mohsen', Maths=19, Physics=17, Chemistry=0, Biology=16, Literature=0, Average=10.4),
        dict(Name='Hafez', Chemistry=13, Biology=0, Physics=17, Literature=0, Maths=15, Average=9),
    ]
```

how to do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should loop around keys and their values. Try it and update your question with your code. Then, we can help you with your code not your direct homework.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you have a dictionary, where the information is arranged based on subjects, where for each subject, you have student marks. You want to collection all information related to each student in separate dictionaries.

One of the approaches which can try, is as below:
Try converting the data which you have into student specific data and then you can calculate the Average of the Marks of all subjects for that student. There is a sample code below.

> Please do note that, this is just a sample and you should be trying
>   out a solution by yourself. There are many alternate ways of doing it and you should explore them by yourself.

The below code works with Python 2.7

```
from __future__ import division

def convert_subject_data_to_student_data(subject_dict):
    student_dict = {}

    for k, v in subject_dict.items():
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if k1 not in student_dict:
                student_dict[k1] = {k:v1}
            else:
                student_dict[k1][k] = v1

    student_list = []
    for k,v in student_dict.items():
        st_dict = {}
        st_dict['Name'] = k
        st_dict['Average'] = sum(v.itervalues()) / len(v.keys())
        st_dict.update(v)
        student_list.append(st_dict)

    print student_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subject_dict = {
        'Maths': dict(Mohsen=19, Sadegh=18, Hafez=15),
        'Physics': dict(Sadegh=16, Hafez=17, Mohsen=17),
        'Chemistry': dict(Hafez=13),
        'Literature': dict(Sadegh=14),
        'Biology': dict(Mohsen=16, Sadegh=10),
    }

    convert_subject_data_to_student_data(subject_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sample_input = {
    'Maths': dict(Mohsen=19, Sadegh=18, Hafez=15),
    'Physics': dict(Sadegh=16, Hafez=17, Mohsen=17),
    'Chemistry': dict(Hafez=13),
    'Literature': dict(Sadegh=14),
    'Biology': dict(Mohsen=16, Sadegh=10),
  }


def foo(lessons):
    result = {}
    for lesson in lessons:
        for user in lessons[lesson]:#dictionary
            if result.get(user):
                #print(result.get(user))
                result.get(user).setdefault(lesson, lessons[lesson].get(user,0))
            else:
                result.setdefault(user, dict(name=user))
                result.get(user).setdefault(lesson,lessons[lesson].get(user,0))
    #return list(result.values())
    return result.values()


#if name == '__main__':
print(foo(sample_input))
```